# Having the following Error: NoMethodError in Posts#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I keep getting the following error. I'm trying to develop my own blogging platform as a way for me to learn and get better.

**Error:**

> Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/posts/show.html.erb where
>   line #36 raised:
>
> undefined method `post_comments_path' for
>   <#:0x007f88f0044248> Did you mean?  posts_path

**app/views/posts/show.html.erb**

```
<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :author %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :author %>
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  resources :posts
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root :to => "posts#index"
end
```

Comment: Post your routes file.

Comment: Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  resources :posts
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root :to => "posts#index"
end

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to update it to look like

#### routes.rb

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

after doing so you should be able see the new routes using `rake routes` or `rails routes` in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a `comments` resource nested in a `posts` resource (or at all) so you cannot create URLs using a comment within a post.

You need to define your comments routes before you can generate URLs for them.

If you want to nest them within `posts`, you should modify your current `resources :posts` line:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

`resources` in your routes files generate helper methods that Rails uses to produce URLs for models, in this case, `post_comments_path`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit following changes to routes.rb file and try again

```
   resources :posts do
      resources :comments
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route file is not correct. Place below code in your routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root :to => "posts#index"
end
```